# Why is localtime system call giving time in UTC in my executable?

Tags: c, datetime, time, posix, localtime

Following is my c++ code:

```
time_t raw_current_time;
time(&raw_current_time);
struct tm* local_time = localtime(&raw_current_time);
```

If I run the above code alone then I get correct local time. But if I embed this code in some other exec then I get time in UTC. Is there any setting which can cause the call to "localtime" to return date in UTC?

Comment: What is the difference between "other exec" and default compilation? Is it on the same PC, OS, etc.

Comment: Yes it's on the same PC. To make it clear, 
Case 1: a.out is generated with just the above code and include libraries. This gives correct local time.

Case 2: foo.out has some code and above code is just included in a cpp file which is used to generate foo.out. This gives local time in UTC. 

As, foo.out and a.out are running on the same machine,  so I wanted to understand if there can be some other setting in foo,out which can cause this.

Comment: `local_time()` isn't the right function, it should be `localtime()`

Comment: It's a typo. I am using localtime only. Correcting the code above.

Comment: Time zone can be changed with `setenv`. Probably the other exec is doing it. Is your `localtime` call made in `main()` before other operations?

Comment: @i486 No it is not.